# Dynamic Drop Down Validation

Tags: jquery

I am having two Drop Downs.
Drop Down 1 having values A,B,C,D
Drop Down 2 having values 1,2,3,4

If A is Selected in Drop Down 1 and 1 is selected in Drop Down 2. It should allow for 1st time. I am using a Dynamic Drop Down.Again if I select A in Drop Down 1 and 1 in Drop Down 2. It should not allow. Kindly provide my a jQuery validation to prevent this. Thanks in advance.

Sample: 
function ValidationCascadingDD() {
        debugger;

```
    $('select[id^="ddlApplicableGroup_infrastructure"]').each(
      //start outerloop against each element
      function (index, element) {
          //find all the items again
          $('select[id^="ddlProfileName_infrastructure"]').each(
            //start inner loop on each item
            function (indexInner, elementInner) {
                debugger;
                if (index != indexInner) {
                    //compare the items here as they are not the same index numbers so are different elements
                    //there are different ways to compare, but you could use jquery again for this
                    //and use the element and elementInner to access each of them.
                    if ($(element).val() == $(elementInner).val())

                        alert("2 dd have the same value:" + element.id + ":" + elementInner.id);
                }
            }
         );
      }
    );


}
```